# ios notifications firebase when app killed redirect specific view

Tags: ios

Good morning, developing an app where I use firebase to receive notifications, I have a problem if I send a notification and the application is killed, I open the first page of the application instead I would like to open a specific view, here is my code

```
func application (_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure ()


    // locally save data for settings

    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore {
        print ("Not first launch.")
    } else {
        print ("First launch, setting UserDefault.")
        UserDefaults.standard.set (true, forKey: "isNotify")
        UserDefaults.standard.set (false, forKey: "isZoom")
        UserDefaults.standard.set (true, forKey: "isCookie")
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "isNotify") {
            registerNotification ()
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set (true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver (self, selector: #selector (registerNotification), name: NSNotification.Name (rawValue: "isNotify"), object: nil)
    return true
}

func registerNotification () {
    if #available (iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current (). RequestAuthorization (options: [. Badge, .alert, .sound]) {(granted, error) in}
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications ()
    }
        // iOS 9 support
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings (UIUserNotificationSettings (types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications ()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, read the notification like that:

```
        let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary
    if notification != nil {
        // Read the notification payload and open related page
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController
    // write a method named like openNotifyPage in rootViewController to push opennotify
    rootViewController.openNotifyPage
```

than push opennotify vewcontroller inside this method

Comment: let notification = launchOptions? [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] come? NSDictionary se notifica! = Nil {let rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController // scrivi un metodo invitato come openNotifyPage in rootViewController per spingere opennotify rootViewController.openNotifyPage}                                                                                        
in this way?